# Ionic 2 : ng2-map info window not opening

Tags: typescript, ionic2, angular2-google-maps

As I am new to Ionic 2 so having an issue in ng2-maps.
Code on html side:

```
<ng2-map zoom="13">
<marker id="{{site.id}}" *ngFor="let site of sites" [position]="[site.latitude, site.longitude]" (click)="openInfoWindow($event)"></marker>
    <info-window id="iw">
      Site Name
    </info-window>
```

and on typescript side

```
openInfoWindow(event) : void {
   var marker = event.target;
   marker.nguiMapComponent.openInfoWindow('iw', marker, {
        lat: marker.getPosition().lat(),
        lng: marker.getPosition().lng(),
    });
}
```

now I am trying to customise info window but its not opening and showing an error:

```
Cannot read property 'openInfoWindow' of undefined
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "marker.nguiMapComponent.openInfoWindow" use "marker.ng2MapComponent.openInfoWindow"